# Google+ sign in asks every time to choose account when activity created

Tags: android, google-plus, google-signin

I want to integrate Google sign in to my game. But i don't want to make sign in process with a button I want it happen once user opens application. 
Whenever MenuActivity is created it asks to choose an account to sign in. But I want it to choose account only once (first time) and remember every time. Here is code:

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener  {

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 007;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();



    if(!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
        signIn();
    }
}

public void startGame(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}



@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
    // be available.
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

    } else {

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create `SharedPreferences`

```
public void saveUser (String key, String value ) {
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("YourPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getUser (String key) {
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("YourPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    return pref.getString(key, "");
}
```

Check user's email if it is empty add `SharedPreferences`

```
if(!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && getUser("email").isEmpty() ){
    signIn();
}


private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
    // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        saveUser("email", acct.getEmail());
        saveUser("name", acct.getDisplayName());
    } else {

    }
}
```